# How to enable ip masquerading/forwarding on CentOS 7

Tags: networking, routing, switching, centos-7

I want to enable IP masquerading/forwarding on CentOS 7, but when I specify `net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, it doesn't work.

Can any one help with this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
$ vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add (or modify) this line in the file:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Finally load the new settings:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: You can leave off the path with `-p`: http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/IPForwarding

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You should add: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1  into file /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf and  /sbin/sysctl -p or reboot.